# android - show pictures in webView that are'nt in filesystem

Tags: android, encryption, filesystems, webview, image

how can I show pictures in `WebView` without saving images into file system?

I have tried to implement my custom `ContentProvider`, but method `openFile` returns `ParcelFileDescriptor` that points into filesystem (or socket). My pictures are in filesystem, but in encrypted form.

I have tried also `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory`, but in android java it is useless (because custom streamHandler can be register in jvm that is not allowed).

I also try html code "img src=\"data:image.gif;base64,R0lGODlhiAAkAMQAANOOk...", but in embedded chrome it's not working :(

pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Android you cannot load images with Base 64 on a webview like that(ur last approach)...

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=596

Check this link out may be you can try with this approach of using content providers

http://blog.tourizo.com/2009/02/how-to-display-local-file-in-android.html

http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/

or

http://downloadandroid.info/2010/07/how-to-display-an-image-from-the-sdcard-in-webview/

Comment: I've got a mistake in html code:
img src="data:image.gif;base64,R0lGODlhiAAkAMQAANOOk...

correct is (typo in mimetype):
img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhiAAkAMQAANOOk...

Answer (score 1):

The first link shows how this is done using the file system, and doesn't seem to resolve the problem described by peter. From what I saw, the only way to resole this is by using a MemoryFile:

[Custom ContentProvider - openInputStream(), openOutputStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148301/custom-content-provider-openinputstream-openoutputstream)

but specifications are not final and it's not implemented on all systems.

Did you find a better way? Is there a way to do it? Is there a way to read a Cursor from a webview?