# Android: ParcelFileDescriptor "createpipe" method 64KB error

Tags: android, pipe, android-contentprovider, parcelable

I have an app that uses the ContentProvider class.
In the openFile method, I need to be able to decode a file & return as a stream of data.
So I decided to use the built in pipe.

The problem is If I use the createPipe method, I am able to write only 64KB into it.
After that I am unable to write data into the Pipe. 
Also note that I cannot read until the data is fully decoded & written into the pipe.

```
package com.aujas.html.viewer.content;
public class LocalFileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final String URI_PREFIX = "content://com.aujas.html.viewer.localfile.dec/";
public static File file;
public String filename;
public ParcelFileDescriptor[] parcels;

public static String constructUri(String url) {
    String editString = url.replaceAll("%20", " ");
    int n = editString.length();
    String uri = editString.substring(5, n - 1);
    Log.d("URI", uri);
    return URI_PREFIX + uri + "\"";
}

public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) {

    Log.d("OPEN", uri.getPath());
    return parcels[0];

}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] as) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Not supported by this provider");
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Not supported by this provider");
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Not supported by this provider");
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] as, String s, String[] as1, String s1) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Not supported by this provider");
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s,
        String[] as) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Not supported by this provider");
}

class DecryptAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... paramArrayOfParams) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            file = new File(paramArrayOfParams[0]);
            Log.d("DecrypOpened", file.toString());
            parcels = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
            Log.d("filebeindec", LocalFileContentProvider.file.toString());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(LocalFileContentProvider.file);

            android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream out = new android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(parcels[1]);
            Cipher ecipher;
            Cipher dcipher;
            SecretKey key;
            String input = "768f8a949de079da";
            byte[] encoded = new BigInteger(input, 16).toByteArray();
            key = new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "DES");
            byte[] iv = new byte[] { (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C,
                    0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A };
            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            InputStream in = new CipherInputStream(fis, dcipher);
            int numRead = 0;
            int n = 1;
            while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                n++;
                out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                Log.d("Error", "SD");
                if (n == 64) {
                    out.flush();
                    out.flush();
                    n = 0;
                }
            }

            Log.d("Decypt Done", out.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("AsyncError", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

}

When I execute this I get to write 64KB only. Since I use 1KB per write, I get 64 Logs after which nothing happens.
Is there a size limit on these pipes? Is there a workaround?
Thanks & Regards
rtindru

Answer (score 7):

Linux kernel (at least the version which is baked into Android) has 64k buffer limit for a pipe.

So, you can't write the whole file (bigger than 64k into it). What you have to do is

a) Create pipe

b) Create writer thread, which will write to this pipe. It will block and wait until reader thread will read the content from pipe.

c) Start this thread

d) Return reader file descriptor to the client.

So, what will happen, both writer and reader will write and read simulteneously. Writer will block when it will fill in the buffer and reader will block, when it emptied the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I expanded out @victor-ronin's answer how into code using code from @commonsware in an answer to another question:

[Custom ContentProvider - openInputStream(), openOutputStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148301/custom-content-provider-openinputstream-openoutputstream/14734310#14734310)

Comment: +1 because of the link. I needed to know the correct way to obtain an `OutputStream` to write in. :)