# Open a file from archive without temporary extraction

Tags: java, android, file, zip

Right now I'm working on an archive browsing application that lets users navigate through archive contents, extract the archives and preview the files inside the archive. I'm using `java.util.zip` API. To preview a file I'm extracting it temporarily and opening it as a usual existing file. As you may understand, that's not a good approach since it won't preview files if there's not enough space to make a temporary extraction. Is there a working solution for passing `ZipInputStream` to an `Activity` to open it as a file? Is there another workaround for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not possible to retrieve just the entries with the entries() method and one the user has chosen one entry retrieve it with the getInputStream(entry) from the JDK 1.6 api it looks like you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you could create a `ContentProvider` that serves up the `ZipInputStream`.

In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe) I demonstrate how to create a `ContentProvider` supporting `openFile()` that uses a pipe created by `ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()` to serve up a file. `createPipe()` returns a pair (two-element array) of `ParcelFileDescriptors` representing the ends of the pipe. You use the second element out of the array to write to via an `OutputStream`; `openFile()` returns the first element out of the array to be passed by Android to the calling process. The caller would use `openInputStream()` to read in what you transfer via the pipe.

In my case, I am sending an asset on which I get an `InputStream` via `AssetManager`. In your case, you would use your `ZipInputStream`.

Note that my sample project assumes it is being run on a device that has a PDF viewer, since it is serving a PDF out of assets and trying to open it via `startActivity()`.

Comment: Thank you, will definitely try that.

Comment: The approach worked fine when I've tried to open an image from archive, which is 6KB in size. When trying to open a bigger file - it gives me an IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe). Can you suggest what may be the case here? Thank you.

Comment: @Egor: There's a 64KB buffer limit on the pipe, though you should be able to work around that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138696/android-parcelfiledescriptor-createpipe-method-64kb-error

Comment: As I see, this workaround logic is implemented in your code, then why won't it work for me?

Comment: @Egor: I do not know. For a moment, I thought it was just that I had chosen a small test PDF, and that I too would crash on a larger one. But I just tried a 230KB one, and I had no problems.

Comment: Another thing I've figured out is that the approach works fine for images of larger sizes, but crashes for audio and video files. Also I've seen the "Unable to create media player" error in logcat. So I presume there's a problem with using this solution with MediaPlayer. Can it be the case and are there any workarounds you can think of? Thank you.

Comment: @Egor: It is certainly possible that `MediaPlayer` has issues, though off the top of my head I can't think of what they'd be, over any other possible client of the stream. Make sure that `getType()` in your provider is returning the correct MIME type for the contents.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18108/discussion-between-egor-and-commonsware)

Comment: @Egor: Well, I was able to reproduce your problem with `createPipe()` and `MediaPlayer`, this time with a simple OGG clip in `assets/`. I have [opened my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920429/anyone-have-mediaplayer-working-with-parcelfiledescriptor-and-createpipe) on this topic to help drive interest, in part because I can supply full sample code that fails. You might want to keep tabs on it to see if I find an answer.

Comment: Will surely keep an eye on it. Thanks again for your interest!

Comment: Mark, thank you for the answer and for the sample!  I used it to return a filtered string from a database column as a file.