# Can ParcelFileDescriptor represent a database column?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

My content provider stores data in SQLite database.  One column is a string.  I would like to attach this string as a file attachment to an email message.

I got this working by implementing `ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)`.  The implementation

1. Queries the column value from the database
2. Stores the returned value in a file
3. Returns the result of `ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)`

Is it possible to avoid these steps and duplication by implementing `ParcelFileDescriptor` that would represent the column value of a record directly?

(I could store the string value in the file to avoid duplication, but I would like to keep using FTS3 facility provided by SQLite)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay, I got it working by using [public ParcelFileDescriptor simpleQueryForBlobFileDescriptor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#simpleQueryForBlobFileDescriptor%28%29)

I can't believe it that I missed this precious piece of information :)

EDIT: there is another method [ParcelFileDescriptor[] createPipe()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#createPipe%28%29) that is more useful if the database column value needs to be transformed before returning to the client.

The example of how to use the method [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863890/1224600).

Comment: wow, i stand corrected.  as of api level 11, there is a built-in function to create a memory-mapped file corresponding to a database blob.  good job.

Comment: Thanks j__m!  MMF is still some sort of duplication, but it is better than creating temporary files by hand.