# android send email with an image screenshot created but not saved

Tags: android, image, email, screenshot

I want to make a screenshot of the screen without saving the image, now I do this to make a screenshot:

```
View view = webView.getRootView();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
```

And to attach the image to the email:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///INFINITA-PL.png"));
```

I do not know how to do it without path.

Comment: cant you just store it in the sdcard temporarily and attach it and then delete it when you exit the app?

Answer (score 2):

The `EXTRA_STREAM` value has to be a `Uri` that can be opened by the Email process. If you don't want to save it as a file and pass that along you will need to implement a `ContentProvider` to make it accessible. [In general this is pretty messy to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542008/returning-a-memory-mapped-inputstream-from-a-content-provider): I can echo the comments in that question (I struggled for awhile to do it without hitting the file system before giving up).

You're probably better served using a File and moving on to the rest of your app.